# Can Postfix require TLS per-domain for inbound _and_ outbound addresses (or IPs)?

Tags: email, postfix, ssl, certificates, smtp

I want to reject email from *certain* senders (ie, the `MAIL FROM`  sender) whose domain appears in a [type:table](http://www.postfix.org/DATABASE_README.html) map if the transport is *not* via `STARTTLS`.  So if `anyone@example.com` sends an email then I want it to reject unless it us running within `STARTTLS`, but the rest of the internet can still send non-TLS email if they would like.  (For outbound TLS validation [smtp_tls_policy_maps](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_tls_policy_maps) works...and I want inbound, too.)

It looks like [smtpd_sender_restrictions](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_sender_restrictions) is the right place to check details about the inbound email's sender but I don't see any TLS-specific options.  (Note that I am *not* looking for client-side certificates, just sender validation claimed by the `MAIL FROM` command.)

1. Can postfix be configured to require TLS based on the sender address?
2. If not, can you contrive a way to filter by FROM address to make sure they send via TLS?

Comment: @thrig, all `*@example.org` should be blocked if not tls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perhaps possible via "[Postfix SMTP Access Policy Delegation](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_POLICY_README.html)"
with Postfix version 2.3 or later; a daemon would check that the
`encryption_protocol` sufficies (exists?) for `sender` whose domain
belongs to to some list (or is in some database table, if there are a
lot of them).

(A milter interface, if the TLS information is passed along, could
also make an accept/reject decision. So if you are already using
MIMEDefang or similar...)