# sendmail: does `TLS_Clt` support CIDR-formatted network blocks in /etc/mail/access?

Tags: ssl, certificates, sendmail, smtp, mail-transport-agent

Does sendmail support `TLS_Clt` access matching based on blocks of IPs? So far the [official sendmail TLS documentation](https://www.sendmail.org/%7Eca/email/doc8.12/cf/m4/starttls.html) I have found does not indicate that it does (nor that it doesn't).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sendmail ships with a `contrib/cidrexpand` script that can convert
`10.2.3.128/25` into a form suitable for inclusion in
`/etc/mail/access`. Also there was a `comp.lang.sendmail` post that
claims to have ruleset code to [Check Arbitrary Network Blocks in CIDR
Notation](https://www.sendmail.org/%7Eca/email/examples/check_nets.html). Another option ([as with Postfix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/708739/can-postfix-require-tls-per-domain-for-inbound-and-outbound-addresses-or-ips)) would be to run a milter such
as MIMEDefang and to let code in the milter handle the accept or reject
routing decision.